Update customer location by script
I'm trying to migrate my Stripe Subscriptions to Tax obligations, but many of my customers haven't filled their location.
Is there a way to automatically update their location by script, without asking them? For example, based on last payment location, or, may be there is better way.
I need this, because, if even one of the customers doesn't update their location, I will have problems with charging them by new version of subscription
I have tried to find any information about setting customer location automatically in documentation.
I'm expecting to set customers location by script.

Hi @Krill, do you have the addresses of your customers saved somewhere else or do you not have any address information at all? Because if you do have addresses somewhere (including IP addresses), you can export the addresses into a CSV file and contact Stripe support to import them for you.

For some users I have only location, from which payment was made, without any other information

Based on the Stripe Docs, I would say that there is no automatically way to do this. Except building a custom solution for yourself.
You can maybe extract country info from a payment intent, but that isn't fully reliable. Because people can use a credit card from another country (through a third party) for example to pay.
What a solution can be is kindly ask your customers to fill in their address to comply with tax obligations. For a non-code solution, I would probably ask my customers to sign in to the customer portal of Stripe, and update their details.
